# Как получить текст между определёнными HTML-тегами с помощью Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Я делаю парсер для одной веб-страницы с помощью Jsoup, и мне нужно, чтобы он получал текст, заключённый между тегами `<h5>` и `</h5>`. Как это сделать?

html-код в виде скриншота, т.к  с его вставкой возникли проблемы:

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (Element headline : doc.getElementsByTag("h5")) {
    System.out.println(headline.text());
}
```